# Pass constraint from View to Controller (MVC)

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, view, constants

I am writing my first project on MVC architecture. I'm a beginner and might be missing out on a simple one. But I just can't figure out how to implement constraint in View and deliver it to Controller.

**View:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewExample: UIView {
    
    var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.text = "Hello, world!"
        
        return textView
    }()
    
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(textView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2)
        ])
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            let ve = ViewExample()
            ve.setupViews()
            view.addSubview(ve)
        }
    
    }
```

What do I need to fix for this to work?

Comment: Hey! I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here. I can see that you've already set up constraints for your `ViewExample` as it gets initialised, and you're adding it to your VC. What exactly do you mean by "passing" the constraints from view to VC? Would be better if you can include what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: Also, off-topic to your question but you don't need to explicitly call `setupViews()` as your `init(frame: CGRect)` gets called as you initialise your `ViewExample()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I still clearly do not know how to formulate a thought. But thanks to your answers - I came to a solution. It turned out to be too easy ..

**View:**

```
class ViewEx: UIView {
    
    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.text = "Hello, world!"
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        return textView
    }()
    
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
         let ve = ViewEx()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            addSubviews()
            setupConstraint()
        }
        
        func addSubviews() {
            view.addSubview(ve.textView)
        }
    
        func setupConstraint() {
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                ve.textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
                ve.textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
                ve.textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
                ve.textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ve.textView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2)
            ])
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the constraints for the view named `ve`. I recommend you to use `SnapKit` cocoapod. it helps you easy to set constraints for your views.
And update like this.

```
import SnapKit 
class ViewExample: UIView {
....
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(textView)
        textView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
            $0.height.equalTo(textView.snp.width).multipliedBy(2)
        }
    }
}

import SnapKit 
class ViewController{
    ....
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let ve = ViewExample()
        ve.setupViews()
        view.addSubview(ve)
        ve.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            $0.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            $0.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

if you don't want to use SnapKit, add the following code to the `viewDidLoad` method.
First, add bottom constraint to `textView` in `setupViews` method.

```
let ve = ViewExample()
ve.setupViews()
view.addSubview(ve)
ve.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
ve.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true 
ve.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true 
ve.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```